# Map subdomains and path to localhost?

Tags: macos, dns, hosts, dnsmasq

For a particular development task, I need this mapping to happen:

`mysub.myservice.com/a/b/* -> localhost/*`

`mysub.myservice.com/anything else` should route as normal.

What is the simplest way to set this up on OSX? I tried dnsmasq but I couldn't figure out how to get this specific mapping to work.

I'm on OSX 10.10.

Comment: You could use a hosts edit in combination with a web server to do this.

Comment: @user193661 This was my initial thought as well.

Comment: If you have many lines in hosts, you can try putting the new entry at the top.